# Laravel 5 has one relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables: drugs table and formulations table. The drugs table has fields id, name, quantity and formulation_id. The formulations table has fields  id and name.

What relationship should I use to get the drugs records including the name of the formulation.

Note that 1 drug record has only one 1 formulation record.

I have tried using hasOne relashionship but doesn't work:

My view looks as follows:

```
@foreach($drugs as $drug)
        <li>
            <a class="padded-list" href="">{{$drug->name}} ({{$drug->formulation->name}})</a>
        </li>
        @endforeach
```

My model relationship in the the Drug model looks as follows:

```
public function formulation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Formulation');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formulation() method in your Drug model should be:

```
public function formulation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Formulation');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `$drug->formulation` return Eloquent Collection, you can't get `name`

You should call `$drug->formulation()->first()->name`

Answer (score 0):

Good day, formulation() in Drug model shoud be

```
public function formulation()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Formulation');
}
```

If one formulation can have many drugs, Drugs() in Formulation model shoud be

```
public function drugs()
{
   return $this->HasMany('App\Drug');
}
```

You can get formulation by this way

$drug->formulation()->first()->name

or

$drug?->formulation?->name

in new php versions